Which account to draw from?
Imagine a retired person with two accounts. One being a traditional (taxable) brokerage account and the other being a Roth IRA. Assume that both accounts are invested in 100% stocks and the mix of stocks is the same in both accounts.
It is my claim that the retired person should deplete the first account in its entirety before touching his Roth IRA. I am not convinced I am right. Am I?

This has been answered before, though I don't have a pointer handy to it. Draw down taxable savings first, then traditional retirement savings, then Roth. If you have a health savings account (HSA), I'm not sure how to optimize that one; note that any spending from it on other than health costs incurs taxes, but if you spend it on health you completely avoid taxes on that money.

@keshlam I do not agree with your comments about pre-tax money in part because of the RMD issue. I  claim that there are cases you should draw down  your pre-tax money to avoid being in a high  tax bracket. However, that is not the issue of this question.

Valid point. Given that I don't spend a great deal (though work on the house this year will double my yearly draw), my taxes have been so much lower than I'm used to that this has simply not been a concern. RMDs may change that.

What you have asked about does take a book, and a spreadsheet to answer.
The number of issues to be balanced can be very large. In addition to determining how to draw down the money in your taxable and Roth accounts, you also have to factor in when should you file for social security. Filing for any pensions also has to be evaluated.

Assume that both accounts are invested in 100% stocks and the mix of
stocks is the same in both accounts.

In addition you have to determine if the mix of investments is correct for you, but an advantage of Roth and non-Roth retirement account is that moving funds from stocks to bonds within the accounts doesn't cause any tax issues.

It is my claim that the retired person should deplete the first
account in its entirety before touching his Roth IRA. I am not
convinced I am right. Am I?

While in the absence of any other information the suggested order would be taxable, traditional, and the Roth; that ignores the impact of Social security, and pensions.
You also haven't considered taxes: pulling money from the taxable accounts, and collecting pensions can make your social security partially taxable. It can also impact your medicare premiums.
The fact that your question avoids tradition retirement accounts, means you don't have to consider traditional to Roth conversions and their impact on your taxes and medicare.
There is also an interesting potential issue with this statement:

the retired person should deplete the first account in its entirety
before touching his Roth IRA.

If all their income came from a Roth (therefore no money from social security or a pension) that would mean zero income taxes, but that would have even been true if the non-Roth income was below the standard deduction. Therefore you might not need to draw the taxable account to zero.

@mshoran_psprep I have worked out a bunch of scenarios with a spreadsheet and it always works out better taking the money out of the taxable account first. However, I am not convinced that I am not missing something.

@mhoran_prep You comment about the medicare  premium is a very good and something I missed.

I don't see the logic of that. All else being equal, the optimum strategy is to have all of your income in the same tax bracket. If you deplete your taxable account first, then you'll start out in a higher tax bracket, and then move to not having any taxable income. It's better to take a mix of the two accounts, so you take advantage of all the low-bracket income you can.

This is a complicated question that is highly dependent upon the "family" retiring.  Often times we focus on an individual but frequently there needs to be a spouse factored into the equation that also qualifies for social security and who may be of a very different age.
While being 5 years different in age may not mean much when a couple is past 40 years old, it does when you talk about when to draw social security and qualifying for Medicare.
You mention the choice between two accounts:  Taxable brokerage and Roth IRA.
Given these two choices you suggest that you should draw down taxable first, then Roth.  This is most certainly incorrect and is too simplified as most also have a pretax IRA/401K.  Even if one did 100% Roth 401K contributions, match dollars would go into pretax.
The goal should be to minimize taxes.  And the mix of Social security, pensions, long and short term capital gains from brokerage, Roth and pretax retirement all has to be evaluated on a case to case basis.  Two couples with identical account balances and investments could have vastly different optimal strategies based on age difference, social security amounts, income needs, or even how much of their brokerage accounts would be short term gains.
You may not realize but under the current tax law a married couple can withdraw up to $94,050 in long term capital gains or qualified dividends tax free.  Reference: 1
Consider a couple where the following was true:

They only had a brokerage and a Roth
The brokerage was all long term capital gains or qualified dividends
They need 100K/year
They had no other income.
The balances in all accounts are a very large number

Then they should take 94K from the brokerage, and the rest from Roth.  They will pay no tax.
Adding one complication changes things dramatically, lets say they also have a pretax account.  They they should withdraw some from that pretax account and none from the Roth.  They could withdraw enough to convert some of that pretax to Roth and still pay no tax.  Or they could withdraw more and pay some tax, but stay within one of the lower brackets.
Its pretty complex and may change as the tax laws change.

"a married couple can withdraw up to $94,050 in long term capital gains or qualified dividends tax free" Do you mean "If they have no other income, a married couple can withdraw up to $94,050 in long term capital gains or qualified dividends tax free" or "In addition to their ordinary income, a married couple can withdraw up to $94,050 in long term capital gains or qualified dividends tax free"? If the former, then your phrasing is rather misleading. If the latter, I'm pretty sure you're wrong.

@Acccumulation yes in addition to other income.  Its kind of amazing.

It looks like it is your taxable income, which includes the long term capital gains, must be below 94050.  Not in addition to your income.    IRS refers to your taxable income, which would include the long term gains.   https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc409
Also - the gains have to be under 94k, not the withdrawal.  That might be a withdrawal of 95k, 180k, 130k, 250k to get to 94k of gains.
